Pip package not found although it is installed in the virtual environment
I have got a python script (https  //github.com/giggls/osml10n/blob/master/transcription-daemon/geo-transcript-srv.py) which did not find pip package, although they are installed.
I tried to run it with activated virtual env and without:
/srv/tile/venv$ /srv/tile/venv/bin/python /srv/tile/venv/bin/geo-transcript-srv.py -s
Loading osml10n transcription server (version 1.2.0): 
ERROR: unable to load python module tltk! Probably the following command will work:
pip install tltk

Error message was:
cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' (/srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py)

/srv/tile/venv$ source ./bin/activate
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv$ /srv/tile/venv/bin/python /srv/tile/venv/bin/geo-transcript-srv.py -s
Loading osml10n transcription server (version 1.2.0): 
ERROR: unable to load python module tltk! Probably the following command will work:
pip install tltk

Error message was:
cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' (/srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py)


Via show and list I find the missing package.
> /srv/tile/venv$ /srv/tile/venv/bin/python -m pip show tltk
Name: tltk
Version: 1.8
Summary: Thai Language Toolkit
Home-page: http  //pypi.python.org/pypi/tltk/
Author: Wirote Aroonmanakun
Author-email: awirote@chula.ac.th
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: gensim, nltk, scikit-learn, sklearn-crfsuite
Required-by: osml10n

> /srv/tile/venv$ source ./bin/activate
> (venv)   /srv/tile/venv$ /srv/tile/venv/bin/python -m pip show tltk
Name: tltk
Version: 1.8
Summary: Thai Language Toolkit
Home-page: http  //pypi.python.org/pypi/tltk/
Author: Wirote Aroonmanakun
Author-email: awirote@chula.ac.th
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: gensim, nltk, scikit-learn, sklearn-crfsuite
Required-by: osml10n


(venv)   /srv/tile/venv$ pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ --------------
blinker                  1.5
...
tltk                     1.8
...
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv$ which python
/srv/tile/venv/bin/python
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv$ 


The first line (shebang) in the python script is changed to the venv:
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv/bin$ cat geo-transcript-srv.py 
#!/srv/tile/venv/bin/python

import argparse
import asyncio
import contextlib
import json
...


The file system looks good to mi too:
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv/bin$ ls -l
total 100
-rw-r--r-- 1 tile tile 2133 May 28 11:46 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 tile tile 1425 May 28 11:46 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 tile tile 3010 May 28 11:46 activate.fish
-rw-r--r-- 1 tile tile 3321 May 28 11:46 activate.nu
-rw-r--r-- 1 tile tile 1754 May 28 11:46 activate.ps1
-rw-r--r-- 1 tile tile 1176 May 28 11:46 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile 9514 May 28 12:53 geo-transcript-srv.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile 4609 May 28 11:48 kakasi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  214 May 28 11:48 nltk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  230 May 28 11:46 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  230 May 28 11:46 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  230 May 28 11:46 pip-3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  230 May 28 11:46 pip3.11
drwxr-xr-x 2 tile tile 4096 May 28 12:53 __pycache__
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tile tile   16 May 28 11:46 python -> /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tile tile    6 May 28 11:46 python3 -> python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tile tile    6 May 28 11:46 python3.11 -> python
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  218 May 28 11:47 tabulate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  212 May 28 11:48 tltk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  216 May 28 11:47 tqdm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  718 May 28 12:53 transcribe.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  217 May 28 11:46 wheel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  217 May 28 11:46 wheel3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  217 May 28 11:46 wheel-3.11
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tile tile  217 May 28 11:46 wheel3.11


The python version look good, in activated venv.
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv/bin$ which python
/srv/tile/venv/bin/python
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv/bin$ deactivate
  /srv/tile/venv/bin$ which python
/usr/bin/python


Site packages are fine too, I think.
/srv/tile/venv$ python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages
/srv/tile/venv$ /srv/tile/venv/bin/python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"
/srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
/srv/tile/venv$ source ./bin/activate
(venv)   /srv/tile/venv$ python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"
/srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages

Does anyone have any ideas what else I could look at?


cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' (/srv/tile/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py)

According to SciPy's release notes scipy.linalg.triu (and some others) were deprecated in SciPy 1.11, and removed in SciPy 1.13.
Install a version of SciPy less than 1.13 and try again:
pip install 'scipy<1.13'


Digging a bit deeper, this is due to the transitive dependency gensim – though in all honesty, it looks like tltk hasn't been packaged very well, since it depends on some packages it hasn't declared itself to depend on. There's an upstream issue for gensim here. A fix has been merged but not released.
I also went ahead and created a PR in the project you're trying to install.
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# uv pip install tltk
 + click==8.1.7
 + gensim==4.3.2
 + joblib==1.4.2
 + nltk==3.8.1
 + numpy==1.26.4
 + python-crfsuite==0.9.10
 + regex==2024.5.15
 + scikit-learn==1.5.0
 + scipy==1.13.1
 + six==1.16.0
 + sklearn-crfsuite==0.3.6
 + smart-open==7.0.4
 + tabulate==0.9.0
 + threadpoolctl==3.5.0
 + tltk==1.8
 + tqdm==4.66.4
 + wrapt==1.16.0
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# python -c 'import tltk'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tltk/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tltk import nlp
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tltk/nlp.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# uv pip install pandas
 + pandas==2.2.2
 + python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
 + pytz==2024.1
 + tzdata==2024.1
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# python -c 'import tltk'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tltk/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tltk import corpus
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tltk/corpus.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# uv pip install requests
 + certifi==2024.2.2
 + charset-normalizer==3.3.2
 + idna==3.7
 + requests==2.32.2
 + urllib3==2.2.1
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# python -c 'import tltk'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tltk/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tltk import corpus
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tltk/corpus.py", line 24, in <module>
    import gensim
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, utils  # noqa:F401
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gensim/corpora/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gensim/corpora/indexedcorpus.py", line 14, in <module>
    from gensim import interfaces, utils
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gensim/interfaces.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils
  File "/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import get_blas_funcs, triu
ImportError: cannot import name 'triu' from 'scipy.linalg' (/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py)
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# uv pip install 'scipy<1.13'
 - scipy==1.13.1
 + scipy==1.12.0
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/# python -c 'import tltk'
(.venv) root@48f1fdfcf444:/#


Thank you very much for your info concerning scipy. I forgot to write, that I found a solution for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78279136/importerror-cannot-import-name-triu-from-scipy-linalg-when-importing-gens
My problem is, that tltk is not found: "ERROR: unable to load python module tltk!".

No - the real issue is the reason printed underneath. It's unable to load tltk because tltk depends on gensim that depends on scipy.

Anyway, my answer is telling you to do the same thing as that answer you linked.
